# Laravel Queue on Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel-5, amazon-ec2

I am looking into google app engine as a alternative to AWS ec2/ELB. One problem I see is that there isn't an obvious way to consume the laravel queue.

If we deploy our laravel app across a few aws ec2 instances, we can use the same deployment process etc to include one instance as the queue runner.

But with app engine, because it is a black box, it seems like we need to do something like a google compute instance to run cli php to run the artisan command.  This is annoying because we will have to worry about scaling the queue worker instances, which kind of defeats the purpose of google app engine.

Is anyone running a fully functioning, (ie with queue) laravel application on google app engine?  If so, any resources you can point to would be helpful?

Is it possible to running php cli commands and supervisor (python) on a google app engine php flex environment?

Comment: Im running into the same problem. Any good resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The Flex runtime already runs supervisord. If you put a file named `additional_supervisord.conf` in the project root directory, it will be added to the existing supervisord.conf.

Comment: Can you give a example?